# Unloading model in torchserve

Tags: handler, torch, status, inference, torchserve

I am getting this while trying to load a model , the status is still unloading :

PS C:\Users\USER\Documents\PFE_PROJECT> curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8081/models/dialect_classifier"
[
{
"modelName": "dialect_classifier",
"modelVersion": "1.0",
"modelUrl": "model_store/dialect_classifier.mar",
"runtime": "python",
"minWorkers": 1,
"maxWorkers": 5,
"batchSize": 1,
"maxBatchDelay": 100,
"loadedAtStartup": false,
"workers": [
{
"id": "9000",
"startTime": "2023-06-07T15:32:02.413Z",
"status": "UNLOADING",
"memoryUsage": 0,
"pid": -1,
"gpu": false,
"gpuUsage": "N/A"
}
]
}
]

I tried restarting torchserve many times but it did not work

Comment: We will need to see the `ts_log.log` to understand more about what is causing the issue.